# cakephp jquery ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp-2.4

When i click selectbox than i want to alert data.But it not working.what is the wrong in ajaxcalling.pls help

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Office');
echo $this->Form->input('office_type', array('type' => 'select', 'id' =>'office_type_id','options' => $settings1,'empty'   => false));
echo $this->Form->end('Save');
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#office_type_id").change(function() {   
    var office_type_id=$('#office_type_id').val(); 

    $.ajax({
          url     : "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'Offices', 'action' =>'getoffices'), true); ?>",
          type    : "POST",
          cache   : false,
          data    : {office_type_id: office_type_id},
          alert(data);
          success : function(data){

          }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not relevant to the original question but I am leaving this here for others who may find this question looking for the same solution I did - essentially, my AJAX requests were lost and were never reaching my controller methods. It had me baffled for a few hours until I realized that I had Cake Authentication & Authorization active. Hence, I needed to allow access using the `beforeFilter` method. Use the following snippet to ensure your AJAX calls do reach your controller methods if you are using CAKE authentication / Authorization

```
/*
 * beforeFilter method
 *
 * @return void
 */ 
    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow();
    }
```

Comment: I had the same problem with 'Security'.

Answer (score 0):

Remove alert before success:

```
$("#office_type_id").change(function() {   
    var office_type_id=$('#office_type_id').val(); 

    $.ajax({
          url     : "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'topics', 'action' =>'test'), true); ?>",
          type    : "POST",
          cache   : false,
          data    : {office_type_id: office_type_id},
          success : function(data){
                  alert(data);
          }
      });
    });
```